# Selector css in Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara, element, selector

How can i implement a selector in capybara with this css? It is too long css.

```
body.home.loggedIn:nth-child(2) 
  div.mainWrapper:nth-child(4) 
  div.clearfix
  div.curvyRedraw.roundbackground
  div.clearboth.clearfix
  div.rightSection_wrapper:nth-child(7)
  div:nth-child(6)
  table.jc_table:nth-child(3)
  tbody:nth-child(2)
  tr.dataRow:nth-child(3)
    > td:nth-child(5)
```

element :MYBTN, 'CSS TOOLOG HERE???'

Answer (score 1):

if you must use this long CSS selector, you could break that up by using capybara's `within` keyword into smaller, more manageable selector strings.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FSession:within

eg

```
within('body.home.loggedIn:nth-child(2) div.mainWrapper:nth-child(4) div.clearfix') do
   ...
end
```

Alternatively - can you find a way to identify the data-rows a bit more specifically?
eg can you put ids or classes on those inner children instead of *having* to use this selector (it feels very brittle).